# How do I fix my normal and cavity map?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have been following along a gamedev.tv tutorial and I am trying to fix my normal maps. I also have this strange leaking spot on my mesh. I'm unsure what would be causing that issue. However, my main issue is the glitching on the normal map and to have a better understanding of how to correct it. I have tried to measure the correct distance for my extrusion when baking, but my low poly would never appear under the high poly.  How can I fix any of these issues?

[image]

[image]

My second issue is in this picture when I select my low poly version of my high poly it sometimes doesn't appear correctly. Also, it never has an orange outline around the character that I have created like with the high poly version. Any idea how I could fix this?

Link to my Blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWIzPnNObf4IMA40mjOULW8o9UP6hZm2/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0):

You've disabled the selectability of the low-poly, enable it again in the *Outliner*:

[image]

As for the bad baking, your *Extrusion* setting is currently 0.025, it's too much for some parts of your mesh, it bakes the inner sides of some faces where the skin folds (neck). If you decrease down to 0.016 you'll fix the problem for your big spot but it won't be enough for some other parts that protude (see image). So I guess you have 3 solutions: Use the *Cage* option (you need to create another low-poly object that will be your cage) / Paint with the basic blue color to remove the bad spots (easiest solution but you'll loose the details on these parts) / combine 2 different normal maps to create one without any bad spot (maybe the best solution).

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! Could I just throw a plane object around the bad areas and paint them basic blue? Or would I be better off re-doing a low poly object of my high poly mesh?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the plane, you can paint on the bad areas in the Image Editor, use the dropper to get the flat blue